# How To Create PostgreSQL Service Manually?

Tags: server, services

For some reason I have to install an old PostgreSQL server, I found the deb file of it, http://community.openscg.com/se/postgresql/archive-packages.jsp

and when I install they are reside on /opt. I know I can symlink to call psql, but:

1. I don't know how to start the service each time I start Ubuntu?
2. Or start the server manually?
3. Do the server need any dependencies or jus one deb file do the job?

Any help would be great.

Comment: As soon as you have installed a package as a "service", it will start up at every reboot. If there are any dependencies left hanging after installing the .deb file, the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` will fix these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone had the same problem with me and using PostgreSQL openscg version can look at this link about how to install it. https://rayhanity.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/installation-of-openscg-postgresql-9-1/

TLDR

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -i ./postgres_9.1.4-1.i386.openscg.deb

[sudo] password for user:

Selecting previously deselected package postgres91.

(Reading database … 118945 files and directories currently installed.)

Unpacking postgres (from …/postgres_9.1.4-1.i386.openscg.deb) …

Setting up postgres91 (9.1.4-1) …

Processing triggers for ureadahead …

ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot

user@ubuntu:~$

user@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgres-9.1-openscg start

user@ubuntu:~$ . /opt/postgres/9.1/pg91-openscg.env
```